# How can I use the Trove4j library in my Gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, import, trove4j

Hello I was wondering how can I import the Trove4j library to my gradle projcet.

Thank you.

My build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'application'
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.0'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre")

}

run{
standardInput = System.in
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include Trove4j library in your Project then you can simply add that library in your build script like below in the dependencies block.

Do a Gradle refresh thie library will be download from maven repository to your local.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.trove4j/trove4j
compile group: 'net.sf.trove4j', name: 'trove4j', version: '3.0.3'
```

After adding Trove4j library to your gradle script in dependecies.

```
dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.0'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre")
compile group: 'net.sf.trove4j', name: 'trove4j', version: '3.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Minor correction: Gradle prefers the `implementation` group these days, so I would use that instead of `compile` (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html).